# While returning value from function in windows form, form is opening

Tags: .net, winforms

```
      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        sTable = getDataTable();//windows form is opening here without doing further operation.
        dropdown.DataSource = sTable ;
        dropdown.DisplayMember = "DESCRIPTION";
        dropdown.ValueMember = "ID";

      }
```

I need to initialize dropdown after setting the sTable value. But onload the form is opening without setting the values.

Comment: I think you are forgetting to call dropdown.DataBind();

Comment: Maybe the returned data table is empty.